# pytest, retrieve test that call fixture

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

Is there a way in a pytest fixture to figure out what test is calling it?

I have tries with inspect but that returns the call_fixture_func
... conftest.py ...

```
@fixture(scope="function")
def resource(app_config):
    curframe = inspect.currentframe()
    caller = inspect.getouterframes(curframe, 2)[1][3]
    resource = app_config.handler.get(caller)
    yield resource
    resource.finish_test()
```

... test file ...

```
@mark.smoke
def test_resource_is_happy(resource):
    print(f"Test starting on {resource.name}")
    ....
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
@pytest.fixture
def your_fixture(request):
    print(request.module)
    print(request.cls)
    print(request.function)


def test_something(your_fixture):
    pass
```

output:

```
test.py <module 'test' from '/path/to/file/test.py'>
None
<function test_something at 0x7fa5205bd140>
```

Read more info here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/builtin.html#_pytest.python.FixtureRequest